# can't install remote ssh extension on visual studio code linux

Tags: linux, ssh, visual-studio-code

I can't install the extension remote SSH, I got the following error when I'm trying to install the extension on Vs code under Linux Fedora 27. The following is the error message:

> Unable to install because, the extension 'ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh' compatible with current version '1.34.0' of VS Code is not found.

The VS Code version specifications:

Version: 1.34.0
Commit: a622c65b2c713c890fcf4fbf07cf34049d5fe758
Date: 2019-05-15T21:55:35.507Z
Electron: 3.1.8
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Linux x64 4.18.19-100.fc27.×86_64

Answer (score 1):

You have to install [Visual Studio Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) to use this extension:

```
Note: The Remote Development extensions require Visual Studio Code Insiders.
```